# Elements are not refresh after call notifyDataSetChanged in the adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I create an adapter and pass a class with an empty list:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Posts providesItemsList() {
    Posts posts = new Posts();
    posts.items = new ArrayList<>();
    return posts;
}
```

After this, I do some network work and call adapter's method:

```
public void setItems(Posts newPosts) {
    Log.i("mytag", "NewPosts items number in the setItems method: " + Integer.toString(newPosts.items.size()));
    posts.items.addAll(newPosts.items);
    Log.i("mytag", "Posts items number in the setItems method: " + Integer.toString(posts.items.size()));
    posts.profiles.addAll(newPosts.profiles);
    posts.groups.addAll(newPosts.groups);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And this is how getItemCount looks like:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.i("mytag", "Posts items number in the getitemcount method: " + Integer.toString(posts.items.size()));
    return posts.items.size();
}
```

In the logs:

```
07-15 18:57:41.967 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the getitemcount method: 0
07-15 18:57:41.967 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the getitemcount method: 0
07-15 18:57:42.005 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the getitemcount method: 0
07-15 18:57:42.005 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the getitemcount method: 0
07-15 18:57:42.118 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: NewPosts items number in the setItems method: 20
07-15 18:57:42.118 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the setItems method: 20
```

How do I properly update my recyclerview?

Comment: Seems like you are either not passing the list of items to the adapter when you instantiated it, or you are updating  the wrong lists, could you please post a snippet of your adapter's constructor and where you instantiate it.

Comment: @NoelOmondi pastebin.com/fYyHfv4E - adapter pastebin.com/Q5zskEmm - activity pastebin.com/ZAsrjHeg - dagger's module

Comment: I have gone through these files and it seems like you are passing an empty Posts item to the adapter, could you check if the setPosts() method in your PostsActivity actually contains posts in it?

Comment: @NoelOmondi Yes it contains, you clearly can see it in logs that I provided in the post.

Answer (score -1):

Try to call `clear()` method on your `List`s before calling `addAll()`

Answer (score -1):

Try to Reinitialize your adapter.